# Recursive power function: approach

Tags: c, recursion, pow

I'm programming for a while now(beginner), and recursive functions are a somewhat abstract concept for me. I would not say I'm stuck, program works fine, I'm just wondering if the function itself could be written without the pow function in the code (but still doing exactly what the problem suggests)

Problem:
http://prntscr.com/30hxg9

My solution:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int power(int, int);

int main(void)
{
    int x, n;
    printf("Enter a number and power you wish to raise it to: ");
    scanf_s("%d %d", &x, &n);
    printf("Result: %d\n", power(n, x));
    return 0;
}

int power(int x, int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    if (n % 2 == 0) return pow(power(x, n / 2), 2);
    else return x * power(x, n - 1);
}
```

I've tried doing this: power(power(x, n - 1), 2);
but execution failed, and I'm still backtracking why.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When rewriting your function, don't lose sight of the main benefit of recursion in this case, which is to reduce the number of multiplication operations required. For example, if n = 8, then it is much more efficient to compute x * x as val1, then val1 * val1 as val2, and the final answer as val2 * val2 (3 multiplications) than to compute x * x * x * x * x * x * x * x (7 multiplications).

This difference is trivial for small integers but matters if you put this operation inside a big loop, or if you replace the integers with very large number representations or maybe ginormous matrices.

Here's one way to get rid of the pow() function without getting rid of the recursion efficiency:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int power(int, int);

int main(void)
{
    int x, n;
    printf("Enter a number and power you wish to raise it to: ");
    scanf_s("%d %d", &x, &n);
    printf("Result: %d\n", power(x, n));
    return 0;
}

int power(int x, int n)
{
    int m;
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        m = power(x, n / 2);
        return m * m;
    } else return x * power(x, n - 1);
}
```

Comment: wont this always return 1 or x ?

Comment: @ufdeveloper Try x = 2 and n = 2 and work out what happens (you should get 4).

Comment: yes, I somehow overlooked the last return statement :)

Comment: @Peter can you explain why this solution is more efficient if in order to do one less iteration (that is basically just one IF and a multiplication) the function has to do 2 divisions

Comment: @Tiago It isn't a matter of "one less"; The difference between "N" and "log(N)" (log base 2) grows larger and larger as N grows.

Comment: @Peter I was misunderstanding the function, now I see why it is so much more efficient

Answer (score 5):

The code:

```
int power(int x, int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    if (n % 2 == 0) return power(power(x, n / 2), 2);
    else return x * power(x, n - 1);
}
```

does not work because when n is even power is called with n = 2 which is even and then power is called with n = 2 which is even and then power is called with n = 2 ... until ... stack overflow!

Simple solution:

```
int power(int x, int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        if (n == 2) return x * x;
        return power(power(x, n / 2), 2);
    }
    else return x * power(x, n - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For the power function (let's say, x to the nth power) you have two cases:

```
exponent=0
exponent=n
```

For the first case, you only need to return 1. In the other case, you need to return x to the power of n minus one. There, you only used the function recursively.

```
int power(int x, n)
{
    if(n == 0) return 1;
    else return x * power(x, n-1);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but the problem states that the computation can be done faster if we approach it as it's described

Answer (score 1):

```
double result = 1;
int count = 1;

public double power(double baseval, double exponent) {
  if (count <= Math.Abs(exponent)){
    count++;
    result *= exponent<0 ?1/baseval:baseval;
    power(baseval, exponent);
  }
  return result;
}
```

This works with positive, negative, and 0 value

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid using `pow()`, right? So you used `power()` instead, leading to a *recursive call within the argument list*. This led to a **segmentation fault**.

First of all, let us understand the cause of the problem. I did a pen and paper run of the algorithm and the result is pretty interesting. It turns out that for any values of x and n, after a certain number of recursions one always ends up getting `power(1, 2)`. This also means that `power(1, 2)` also leads to `power (1, 2)` after a certain number of recursions. Thus, this `power()` within a `power()` leads to an *infinite recursion* and thus the **stack overflow**.

Now, to your question. Yes, this can be done without using pow() because pow(a, 2) can simply be written as a*a. So, here is a slight modification to your code:

```
int power(int x, int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    if (n % 2 == 0) return power(x, n / 2) * power(x, n / 2);
    else return x * power(x, n - 1);
}
```

But then, why do it this way? A more efficient way would be as follows.

```
int power(int x, int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    if (n % 2 == 0) return power(x * x, n / 2);
    else return x * power(x * x, n / 2);
}
```

This reduces the number of recursions needed, making the code more time and space efficient. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Simple but does n number of multiplications. Above examples are more efficient because they group two operations in one iteration

```
int power(int x, int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 1;

    return x * power(x, n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in **ruby** which works for negative exponents as well

```
# for calculating power we just need to do base * base^(exponent-1) for ex:
# 3^4 = 3 * 3^3
# 3^3 = 3 * 3^2
# 3^2 = 3 * 3^1
# 3^1 = 3 * 3^0
# 3^0 = 1

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# OPTIMIZATION WHEN EXPONENT IS EVEN
# 3^4 = 3^2 * 3^2
# 3^2 = 3^1 * 3^1
# 3^1 = 3^0
# 3^0 = 1
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

def power(base, exponent)
  if(exponent.zero?)
    return 1
  end
  if(exponent % 2 == 0)
    result = power(base, exponent/2)
    result = result * result
  else
    result = base * power(base, exponent.abs-1)
  end

  # for handling negative exponent
  if exponent < 0
    1.0/result
  else
    result
  end
end

# test cases
puts power(3, 4)
puts power(2, 3)
puts power(0, 0)
puts power(-2, 3)
puts power(2, -3)
puts power(2, -1)
puts power(2, 0)
puts power(0, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach with C++, works only with non-negative numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long long  power(long long x, long long y) {
if (y == 0) {
    return  1;
}
else {
    y--;
    return x*power(x,y);
 }
}
main() {
long long n, x;
cin >> n >> x;
cout << power(n,x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int pow(int a, int n) {
    if(n == 0) return 1;
    if(n == 1) return a;
    int x = pow(a, n/2);
    if(n%2 == 0) {
        return x*x;
    }
    else {
        return a*x*x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming the answer can fit into integer data type.

Comment: It would be great if you'd not only just drop some code, but also give an explanation of what is going on in his and your code. It helps the question author and other users. It's good if it works, but knowing why is even more important in my opinion.