# Why is this power function causing a stack overflow c#

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I have the following power function that I have written in c#:

```
public static double pow2(double x, double n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
    {
        stepAccumulator++;
        return pow2 (x, Math.Floor (n / 2.0)) * pow2 (x, Math.Ceiling (n / 2));
    }
}
```

When I run the program I simply say `result=pow2(1,1000);` and then time the function using a `Stopwatch` object and then print the result at the end. Unfortunately, when I run this program I get the following error: **Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException**. Why is this happening and how can I stop it?

Comment: Yet again I have to ask: Does no one bother to debug code anymore? Surely you'd put a breakpoint at the top and check the value of `n` each time through? If you've done that why not tell us the results? If you haven't, why not do it?

Comment: because n/2 is never 0

Comment: Nah, n reaches 0. On breakpoint, n=1000, n=500, n=250, n=125,.. n is divided by two each time and once it reaches 0, it never returns 1 with `if(n==0){return 1;}` and just continues to fluctuate between 0.0 and 1.0

Comment: Why would you think that repeatedly dividing a number by 2 will eventually give 0? That's not how math works.

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline - note that code check is on `Ceiling`/`Floor` so `Floor(n/2)` eventually reaches 0 (unlike `Ceiling`)... Note that Floor/Ceiling let one to only compute whole powers...

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Apologies.

Answer (score 5):

Your `Math.Ceiling(n/2)` case will never call `pow` with `n == 0` because `Math.Ceiling(1/2) == 1`.  Once your `pow2` is called with `n == 1` the next two calls will be:

```
return pow2 (x, Math.Floor (1 / 2.0)) * pow2 (x, Math.Ceiling (1 / 2));
```

Which is the same as :

```
return pow2 (x, 0) * pow2 (x, 1);
```

Which results in another call to `pow2` with `n == 1`, so you algorithm never terminates

Comment: Thank you very much. That's the answer I was looking for. Unfortunately, there must be a way to solve this algorithm. It was given as an instruction to me to make a power function that works with that exact recursive call.. perhaps there is a way to rewrite this function into a working power function? The instruction was given to me by my professor who has a PhD in Algorithms. This must have a way to work, I must have written it incorrectly.

Comment: You'll have to check on your instructions for that.  Your algorithm doesn't look like a normal recursive implementation of power.  Those usually only have one recursive call like the examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389184/recursive-power-function-approach